# Which one is best for Iphone REST API or SOAP?

Tags: iphone, rest, soap

I am working on iPhone Applications. Recently i have used SOAP api to integrate with iPhone application. my main aspect of this particular query is whether SOAP is best or REST is best considering performance issue as a iPhone application.

I have tried with SOAP, there will be frequent crashes happened to me. so is it better to use REST to overcome from such issues.

Currently my main concern is to achieve best performance in application and i am looking for such solution from you all.

Comment: Why do you think REST would result in fewer crashes? Have you investigated why SOAP is causing instability, before switching your code over?

Answer (score 11):

SOAP is bulky and heavy when compared to REST services.

Prefer REST as it is simple and very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer data from web to your app, prefer JSON. It is faster and better than xml.